# pad_sequences changes the whole array in TensorFlow - Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, padding

I am practicing the LSTM networks in `tensorflow`. I am currently learning about masking and padding that are used in different lengths of inputs. However, when I use `pad_sequences` method, I am observing a strange behavior.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

max_length = 8
X = []

for i in range(5):
    length = np.random.randint(1, max_length+1)
    data = np.random.randn(length, 4)
    X.append(data)

print(X)

[array([[ 0.23830355,  0.32776379,  0.19888588,  0.27975603],
        [-0.84285787, -0.76969476,  0.01841278, -0.88942005],
        [-1.51102046, -0.18195023, -1.32969908,  0.19397443]]),
 array([[-0.10567699, -0.79576066,  0.55816155, -0.70074442],
        [-0.0386933 ,  0.54722971, -1.71065981,  1.00276863],
        [ 1.82485917, -1.19912133, -1.91067831,  0.37120413]]),
 array([[ 0.03045082,  0.41638681, -1.49605253, -0.41086347],
        [ 0.65929396, -0.09148023, -0.22942781, -0.76795439],
        [ 0.56964325,  0.7318355 ,  1.41732107,  0.38632864],
        [ 0.78369032,  1.41461136, -1.32514831,  1.27382442],
        [-1.4822751 ,  0.44608809, -0.01882849,  0.78095785]]),
 array([[ 1.59961346, -0.74595856, -0.91752237, -1.81289865],
        [ 0.13899283, -0.93514456, -0.68329374, -0.91662576],
        [ 1.09513416,  0.83803103,  0.63074595, -1.88594795]]),
 array([[ 1.64358502, -2.28208926, -0.26371596, -0.59044336],
        [ 1.52187054,  1.42308418,  0.0275608 , -0.09422734]])]
```

First, I create a random dataset with different lengths. Now, I go ahead and use `pad_sequences`  method to make each input vector the same length.

```
mask_val = -1
X_padded = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_length, padding='post', truncating='post', value=mask_val)
print(X_padded)
array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [-1,  0, -1,  0],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0, -1,  1],
        [ 1, -1, -1,  0],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1]],

       [[ 0,  0, -1,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  1,  0],
        [ 0,  1, -1,  1],
        [-1,  0,  0,  0],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1]],

       [[ 1,  0,  0, -1],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  0,  0, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1]],

       [[ 1, -2,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  1,  0,  0],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1]]])
```

As you can see, for every missing data, `tensorflow` uses `-1` as desired. However, all other entries are messed up. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `dtype='float32'` as an argument, else by default the func will round up to nearset integer

```
X_padded = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X, padding='post', truncating='post', value=mask_val, dtype='float32')
```